# How to find out the total number of groups created by a user

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

i'm playing with these code and it fails:

```
$fql = "SELECT name FROM group WHERE gid IN (SELECT name FROM group WHERE version=1) AND creator=me()";
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' => $fql,
));
echo count($ret_obj["name"]);
```

does anyone knows how to count() the no. of groups a person has created. Thanks
i'm using PHP-SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like group table has only 1 field gid as indexable which makes it impossible to filter user groups in FQL. Possible bug.

What you can do is make a graph API call to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?fields=name,owner
```

and then filter results by owner.id and count them.

hope this helps

Comment: thanks @anatoly that was really useful. after query like you said i use it like this: `$groups = $facebook->api("/me/groups?fields=name,owner");
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($groups['owner'] as $my_group) {
     if ($my_group['id'] == $user_profile['id']) {
            $j++;
         }
    }
    echo "Total no. of groups i create: $j ";` but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aakash Singh: pls clarify what doesn't work? Do you get any error? Does the query return results, etc. thanks

Comment: sorry, it works now.
`foreach ($groups['owner']['id'] as $my_group)` was the trick. thank you very much :)